# How to query an external SQL database - iPhone app

Tags: iphone, sql, ios, sqlite

I've used sqlite3 before in an iPhone application, but how can I query out to an external SQL database sitting on my website?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your app does not perform the actual query. The proper way to do this is to set up an API for your website so that the site does the querying and returns the appropriate data to your app.

Your API is generally going to be comprised of a number of end points that return data formatted for your app. For example, you might create a PHP or Python page that queries your database for all of the posts for a given user and returns them in a JSON or XML encoded array. (The data format is totally up to you. There are frameworks for parsing  both formats available for iOS.)

For example, let's say you have a PHP page on your server that returns the current day of the week. Your PHP would look something like this:

```
<?php
  echo date("l");
?>
```

Let's imagine that you've saved this as http://example.com/dayoftheweek.php

I recommend using the [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) framework for performing HTTP requests from within your app. That said, let's go ahead and set up a connection to your PHP page. Assuming you have ASIHTTPRequest all set up in your project, here's what a request might look like:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/dayoftheweek.php"]
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[request setDelegate:self];
```

Now, you need implement the ASIHTTPRequest Delegate methods, to parse the returned data. The method which handles a completed request is shown here:

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{
   //Here you would store the returned data and/or parse it
}
```

To implement an API, your PHP pages would be more complex. You would build a more complex request , passing in variables and such, and the PHP page would act like a regular web service, returning the data that you have requested.

Comment: but what type of http requests? how exactly do I make an API? is that php? what would be an example of a way to do this?

Comment: I don't think he really needed a duplicated answer.

Comment: @StanLe - I've updated with a basic example. @pt2ph8 - I don't think so either, which is why I've updated my answer. ;-)

Comment: Excellent example. I truly appreciate it. The only thing I'm uncertain of is the following: in PHP, how do I "return" data? I've only ever printed data to the screen.

Comment: @StanLe - That is exactly what you will be doing, only you may be printing it inside of XML tags or JSON wrappers.

Comment: Oh, you mean I still print to the screen?

Comment: Yes, whatever is printed to the screen is delivered to the app as part  of the response.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean MySQL. Usually access to MySQL databases is forbidden from the outside, and for good reason. You may want to write an API that accesses your database instead. Your iPhone app would communicate with this API to insert and retrieve data.

Comment: So what sort of API? Would I make like some php scripts or something?

Comment: Yeah. The simplest thing you could do is a PHP script that returns JSON or XML formatted data based on the parameters you pass to it. Then you parse that data from your app using ASIHTTPRequest plus one of the many JSON and XML libraries around (I recommend YAJL for JSON and GData for XML) and do something with it.

Comment: You can use web services. Lets say you want to get an ID for some user from server database. To achieve this, there can be a web service API -(NSNumber*)IDForUserWithName:(NSString*)username. This call goes to your server which internally fetch the ID for the username passed in from the database.

Comment: @subhash I think I'd be able to figure out how to make a php file which takes in a query, or even makes a query to my MySQL database. But my concerns are: how would I wrap those results up and read them in Objective-C. What would the objective-C side of things look like. I've done SQL queries before, but have printed them to the computer screen...

Comment: @StanLe, How are you communicating with the server from your app. You are sending simple http request or soap based web service? If you are using a simple http request, in which format you rae getting the response? Is it in XML format?

Comment: The only thing I've done with pinging to a server is to grab a text file off a server using NSData dataWithContentsOfURL. I've never done anything more complicated than that. What would you suggest? How should I grab the results of the MySQL request?

Answer (score 0):

@StanLe: You cannot use SQL Server or mySQL within native app directly. However you can communicate your application with external SQL Databases with following way.

1. Create XML API using PHP, or C# or any tool which provide XML file in result.
2. Use some parser (NSXMLParser) in xcode, which can read the tags of XML page.

Here is [example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/iPhone/parsing_iPhone.aspx)

Here is [sample Code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SeismicXML/Introduction/Intro.html)

Another Very [Simple Example](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/parsing-an-xml-file/)

if still any confusion please write back.

Comment: I am a little familiar with PHP and have made SQL queries in PHP before. The only thing that concerns me is that I have printed the results of the query to the console (to the computer screen). How would I wrap up those results and read them in Objective-C?

Comment: can you tell me some details, like what database and platform you are using, and what kind of results you want to see in native app ?

Comment: Excelent links. The only thing I'm stuck with is how to run a php file on my server such as www.mysite.com/myfile.php from objective-c and get the results back. I want to be able to run a php file with a particular input (such as a name) which will be used to query the database. Then the PHP will return a row from my MySQL database. Then my Objective-C will get that result.

Answer (score 0):

The approach that is used to communicate with any external database is via Webservices (Which we are calling here as API). you make a request to server which is normally a function call on server and the server replies you with requested data.

You can go through [This](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/11/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-intro-to-soap-web-services/).As Far as PHP and other relevant terms are concerned then You will have to make some efforts and google some code. [This](http://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json) can also be of some use . Normally the webservices written for iPhone make use of XML/JSON for iPhone. JSON/XML parser are available